# Why is this NDA not available in openFDA?

Tags: openfda

I'm working on a project that annotates FDA label text. We're trying to use the openFDA API to get information about specific NDA IDs. I'm trying to query information about `NDA206038` using the `/search` endpoint. I get a `404` response.

However, when I look in Drugs@FDA: https://www.accessdata.fda.gov/scripts/cder/daf/index.cfm?event=overview.process&varApplNo=206038 I get a valid page with all sorts of data.

Why is this particular NDA not available through openFDA? Is there a document somewhere that lists what types of labels are not indexed in openFDA?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The drug you are referring to -- ORKAMBI® (lumacaftor/ivacaftor) -- apparently has changed its dosage form. Approval of a new dosage form of a drug requires a new NDA. The most recent NDA approval for this drug is **NDA211358**, and openFDA will include only the most recent NDA number by design. The following query will return the results you would expect: https://api.fda.gov/drug/label.json?search=openfda.application_number:NDA211358.

Comment: Is there a way to query `api.fda.gov` and figure out that a particular NDA number is not the most recent? Right now if I query on a valid but non-recent NDA it gives me a `NOT_FOUND` response which looks exactly the same as a request for an invalid NDA ID like "blahblah"

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think openFDA offers such capability. You can always get the most recent NDA off of the "openfda" section by querying by drug brand name, for example: https://api.fda.gov/drug/label.json?search=openfda.brand_name:ORKAMBI